# How to implement a java daemon program in weblogic?

Tags: java, servlets, service, weblogic

I have the task to port a standalone java deamon program to J2EE on weblogic.

Old: The java program starts two threads which loop endlessly based on an interval that can be configured via a properties file.

New: The program should run on weblogic 10.1.x and start when the managed server it will deployed to is started or the servlet is initialized and it shouldn't have to be invoked by a client.

I know already that creating your own threads is highly discouraged for weblogic so I'll search for another way to make this happen. I already tried via startup class, but that means the server remains in the state STARTING forever because naturally the programm is designed to run forever, I didn't know the server is actually waiting for the Startup Class to end. Next best thing I know of would be the usual servlet by calling its URL once and implement starting the programm in it. Even then, how would you prevent the browser from getting hung up on the servlet call (because it does run forever) without making the program logic asynchronous by creating a thread? Also I read something about Listeners, would that be the thing I should be looking for?

One last thing, I definitly need to run it on weblogic, so suggestions for other solutions wouldn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confusing question because it's so basic... You just need to create a web service with your endless loops in it. You don't need to hit a URL to start it. Just deploy a .war or .ear file with your code and you're done.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webserv/example.html

Comment: Sorry, it's just that I have no experience with this stuff whatsoever and there is no time for a proper training course. This example needs a client to invoke the application. However the program I'm porting shouldn't have to be invoked using a client, this should be handled on starting the managed server itself, next best thing would be the mentioned servlet. Sorry if I haven't made that clear.

Comment: This is a solid working example: http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-run-java-services-or-background-daemon-processes-in-an-application-server-or-web-container/ and as people have noted in the comments on that blog you may want to look into Quartz Scheduler. But if you're being forced into putting a square peg into a round hole, just go the threads route.